# Loop through dataset and stop and select

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of data that I want to loop through. In column A the data will have a code, when this code changes I want the loop to stop and select all of the codes above. I have asked the question before and got helpfulle advice, I have pasted the code provided form Error 1004 below.

When I go through the code using F8 it does seem to loop through the code in column A but does not stop or select all of the data with the same code.

```
Sub test()

    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long, j As Long, StartPoint As Long
    Dim strValue As String

    strValue = ""
    StartPoint = 2

    'With statement refer to Sheet1. Change if needed
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        'Find Last row of column A in Sheet1
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        'Loop starting from row 2 to LastRow variale. Change Starting position if needed
        For i = 2 To LastRow

            If i >= StartPoint Then

                strValue = .Range("A" & i).Value

                For j = i + 1 To LastRow

                    If .Range("A" & j).Value <> strValue Then
                        .Range("A" & j - 1 & ":B" & j - 1).Select
                        Exit For
                    End If

                Next j

                StartPoint = j

            End If

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

The Excel sheet will look like the following:

```
Portfolio   Owner Name
7000107510  Owner Name 1
7000107510  Owner Name 1
7000107510  Owner Name 1
7000107510  Owner Name 1
7000107510  Owner Name 1
7000108762  Owner Name 2
7000108762  Owner Name 2
7000108762  Owner Name 2
7000110007  Owner Name 3
7000110007  Owner Name 3
7000114711  Owner Name 4
7000114711  Owner Name 4
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do beyond selecting some cells?

Comment: What is your end goal? Selecting cells is not a good practice, you can do whatever you need without the need of selecting, so if you tell us what is the next step we might be able to help you in a different way to avoid the selecting.

Comment: I want to select the cells with additional columns, and past this in a different worksheet

Comment: Elaborate this, because you can copy the cells without selecting... for example `.Range("A" & j - 1 & ":B" & j - 1).Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TargetSheet").Range("A1")` that would paste.

Comment: Why not use AutoFilter and remove the need to loop?

Comment: This is a function I want to use more often in the future, therefore I would like to built a macro to do this

Answer (score 0):

This will do the Job:

```
Sub test()

    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long, j As Long, StartPoint As Long
    Dim strValue As String

    strValue = ""
    StartPoint = 2

    'With statement refer to Sheet1. Change if needed
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        'Find Last row of column A in Sheet1
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        'Loop starting from row 2 to LastRow variale. Change Starting position if needed
        For i = 2 To LastRow + 1

            If i >= StartPoint Then

                If Not .Range("A" & i).Value = .Range("A" & i - 1).Value Then
                    .Range("A" & StartPoint & ":C" & i - 1).Select
                    StartPoint = i

                   ' Add your additional code here After Selecting   

                End If


            End If

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: This is working when I'm using F8. But when I run the macro It skips all the codes and stops with only the last code selected. Is there a way to stop at the first code switch? (with lack of better explanation)

Comment: Yes You can stop it ...But then the loop won't continue further. Because we will have  to stop the macro for tht. Or maybe just add Break point on the line where we are selecting cells.

Comment: Adding a [BreakPoint](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/4/8/debugging-vba-code-adding-breakpoints)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'd would do it:

```
Option Explicit
Sub test()

    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim C As Range
    Dim CopyRange As Range


    'With statement refer to Sheet1. Change if needed
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        'Find Last row of column A in Sheet1
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        'Loop starting from row 3 to LastRow variale. Change Starting position if needed
        For Each C In .Range("A2:A" & LastRow)
            If C = C.Offset(-1) Then 'check if the ID is the same as the row above
                'if it is, create a range with the cells with the same ID
                If CopyRange Is Nothing Then 'start the range if is empty
                    Set CopyRange = .Range("A" & C.Row & ":B" & C.Row)
                Else 'add the new cells if not empty
                    Set CopyRange = Union(CopyRange, .Range("A" & C.Row & ":B" & C.Row))
                End If
            Else 'when you find a different ID then copy the range you already had
                CopyRange.Copy Destination:=Range("A1") 'change Range("A1") for the range where you want to paste
                Set CopyRange = Nothing 'empty the range
                Set CopyRange = C 'renew the range with the current ID (new one)
            End If
        Next C
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm getting an error at the Copy Range.Copy Destination:=Range(A1)

Comment: You need to change that @Peter I can't know where do you want to paste, give me some more info and I can edit the answer.